# .NET Core 3.1 e Restful Api Validation

Tags: c#

Estou usando `.NET 3.1` para console e estou validando uma `API REST`, gostaria de saber como posso validar se tal API possui no máximo 2 caminhos para `GET` como por exemplo: `/veiculos`, `/veiculos/{id}`.

Gostaria de saber como faço tal validação.

Comment: Como assim validação? Onde vc quer "validar" isso?

Comment: validar? é só olhar para o código, pois vc é quem programa as rotas, a controller e as actions

Comment: Quem fez a API REST?